# CSS (position:absolute + left:50% = max-width:50%)?

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website where I'm having a temporary problem, I've a `div` with **CSS** like this:

```
.box{
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 75%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,0);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%,0);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,0);
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
}
```

You can see a simple [**JSFiddle** here](http://jsfiddle.net/c3LNL/3/), where the `box1` is working correctly, it has short text and the `width: auto;` is working perfectly ...

But the second box `box2` has long text and `max-width: 75%;`, but it's not working correctly, you can notice that its width looks like `50%`

My question is from where did the `box2` get `50%` width ?? And how can I fix that issue ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you want them in the same type of selector `box`?

Comment: it's just an example about my real problem, both of the `div`s are `li` in my website and they are used in a ticker with opacity effect.. so I need them to have the same class

Comment: What width do you want on each div?

Comment: I added `box1`  `box2` classes just to fix the vertical position in the example, it has no relative to the problem

Comment: I want `width: auto; max-width: 75%` on both of them, but with long text the second property doesn't work

Comment: The problem is that most elements/content won't force the element to it's maximum width unless they are forced to. If you add non-breaking content (See here - [**Jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/c3LNL/5/) then the max-width takes effect **but** the overflow isn't visible.

Comment: You have `width: auto; max-width: 75%;` on them. What width do you want each to appear to have?

Comment: It might be more useful to see the actual HTML structure. It's not clear to me why you are using position absolute. You say this is a ticker of some kind...what kind? A JSfiddle would be useful here I feel.

Comment: I want `box1` to look as it is now, fits its content, but `box2` because its content is larger that 75% of the screen, so I want its width to appear '75%' of the screen width

Comment: @Paulie_D this is the original website http://jmu.edu.iq/ , I guess it doesn't work with you, because it has a proxy problem, it doesn't work outside my country

Comment: That's why you should be making a JSfiddle. Frankly, I think you may have go a different way here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may achieve the desired layout using an extra tag (a `span` for example)

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/c3LNL/7/)**

*HTML :*

```
<div class="box box1"><span>box1 Lara had been back and</span></div>
<div class="box box2">
    <span>box2 Lara had been back and forth along the river path many times in her short life. Her people had not created the path, it had always been there, like the river, but their deerskin-shod feet and the wooden wheels of their handcarts kept the path well worn. Lara’s people were salt traders, and their livelihood took them on a continual journey</span>
</div>
```

*CSS :*

```
.box{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}

.box1{
    top: 20px;
}

.box2{
    top: 100px;
}
.box span{
    display:inline-block;
    max-width:75%;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: +1 Agreed..I didn't want to suggest this without seeing the full HTML but this is the best option if the code is editable.

Answer (score 4):

Use style `width: fit-content;`.
Example:

```
.center-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 0;
  width: fit-content;
  transform: translate(-50%);
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

This "center-wrapper" (your "box") now grows with child and also is centred.

Answer (score 1):

> If the element has 'position: absolute', the containing block is
>   established by the nearest ancestor with a 'position' of 'absolute',
>   'relative' or 'fixed' .
>   [reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details)

Where the html tag element is the containing block in your case, a possible solution would be to add a container `<div>` and set its position to `relative` ,  [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c3LNL/10/).

Comment: How could it be if I need the width of the `container` fits the width of the screen, which mean `100%` ..

Comment: Set the container's width to 100% o.o

Comment: We returned to the same issue, the `box2` width looks like 50% not 75%

Comment: The width of your divs gets limited to 50% of the **container** due to the absolute positioning of them 50% from the left side of the window.

Answer (score 1):

First you have `left: 50%;`. This makes the div 50% width since it has `width: auto;` and there are only 50% of the page left for it to fill. After that, the div is moved 50% of it's own width to the left, to be centered.

So we can conclude that the `width: auto;` and `left: 50%;` is calculated before `transform: translate(-50%,0);`. Probably in that order.

So that's the answer to you're question why the div doesn't grow bigger than 50%.

Comment: I noticed that while working, but I was wondering if I can make `transform: translate(-50%,0);` works before `width: auto;` and `left: 50%;` , I guess no, without JS .. Do you have an idea about doing such thing ??

Comment: I experimented a bit with `margin: 0 auto;` instead of `left: 50%;` and `transform: translate(-50%,0);` for centering. However, this makes the div always use `max-width: 75%;`. Not wrapping the text if it's short, as you wish. And since you had gotten an accepted answer for accomplishing the desired result I didn't spend more time on it.

Comment: i saw that postion relative does not have such issues. width remains the same as parent if its block element. if its inline-block then it will use its own width and max width will be that of parent automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You type max-width: 75% this mean your div could have width less than 75% so

If something inside div is bigger then 75% div will still have 75% but
if something inside div is lower then 75% div will suit width to this element.

Try to add width:75% instead

Comment: if I add `width:75%` the first box won't fit it's content !!

Comment: my question is from where did the `box2` get `50%` width ??

Comment: @MujtabaFathel you're telling the browser that the `max-width` is 75%, but also that the `width` is `auto`. So the browser will try to make the `div` as small as possible. I don't think you can achieve what you want by having them in the same selector.

Comment: this is not 50% div suit to text inside. So try to use min-width:75%

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to center your divs? Can you set the horizontal margin to `auto` instead?

```
.box {
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 10px auto;
  max-width: 75%;
}
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/riqafo/2/edit

In your original code, the width of your divs gets limited to 50% of the window due to the absolute positioning of them 50% from the left side of the window.

The transform then slides the divs back over to the left by 50% of the window width, but they keep their reduced size.

The automatic width allowed the upper div's width to collapse downward to its contained text. This wasn't relevant to the lower div, since the length of its text would exceed the width of the window if allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this can solve your issue without changing your structure.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Taxellool/42hpg/)

```
.box{
    position: absolute;
    width: auto;
    display: table;
    max-width: 75%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #000;
    color: #fff;
    margin: auto;
}

.box1{
    top: 20px;
}

.box2{
    top: 100px;
}
```