# Can't make max-width work when using absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, css-position

I can't get `max-width` to work when using absolute positioning. In https://jsfiddle.net/jn2bs6ax/ the item should take as little width as possible, up to the max-width of 1000px. But it's taking a width of about 50% and wrapping the text. How to make it work? If I set the max-width to something small like 300px it works, but anything larger than what it's width currently is doesn't cause it to expand.

This example just shows an item that's been absolutely positioned to the center **below** an item, but I use `transform`, `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` to position things in all 4 directions relative to an item. The solution should work with all 4 cases.

There's a similar question [CSS (position:absolute + left:50% = max-width:50%)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24969364/css-positionabsolute-left50-max-width50) but the answer only works with centering below but not for all cases like positioning to right of an item vertically centered.

```
<div class="relative">
  text
  <div class="absolute">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim recusandae doloribus nesciunt unde vitae quis aliquid laborum adipisci ipsa, dolorem repellendus nulla iure atque minus fuga sunt rem eaque animi.</div>
  text
</div>
```

css

```
.relative {
  position: relative;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: grey;
  max-width: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting     `display: inline-table;` or     `display: table;`

```css
.relative {
  position: relative;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: grey;
  max-width: 1000px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  display: inline-table;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
  text
  <div class="absolute">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim recusandae doloribus nesciunt unde vitae quis aliquid laborum adipisci ipsa, dolorem repellendus nulla iure atque minus fuga sunt rem eaque animi.</div>
  text
</div>
```

Comment: Is this actually working for you? I've tried it with inline-table and table and the output is the same as in my question.

Comment: See the output it's not same

Comment: I've tried it here and in jsfiddle and it's identical output. I'm not sure why we're seeing different things. Can anyone else try and let me know what you see?

Answer (score 0):

Try add `width: 100%;` for your class along max-width in any place.

```css
.relative {
  position: relative;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: grey;
  max-width: 1000px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
  text
  <div class="absolute">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim recusandae doloribus nesciunt unde vitae quis aliquid laborum adipisci ipsa, dolorem repellendus nulla iure atque minus fuga sunt rem eaque animi.</div>
  text
</div>
```

Comment: If the text contains only a few words the box shouldn't take up 1000px. That's the point of setting MAX width and not width. Unfortunately this answer doesn't work.

Comment: @user779159 whats is your desired result? You want set max-width:1000px right?

Comment: when the text is sort that time also you want to apply `max-width?`

Comment: Max width means it's the maximum width, not the width in all cases. Otherwise I would have just set width and not had this question at all.

Comment: I am not clear with your question and desired output. Can you brief with short note or picture.

Comment: If the text is anything less than 1000px, it should be the size of the text only. If it's greater than 1000px, the box shouldn't exceed 1000px and the text inside it should wrap. It's not a special requirement, it's just the definition of maximum width. Does it make sense?

Comment: You can set the max-width to 3000px, but if only 400px is available, than the width will be **400px**. Everything works as expected, there is no error anywhere, just your understanding of css max-width is wrong.

Comment: @skobaljic the issue is not the max-width but the left:50% used with position:absolute that add another restriction making the width no more bigger than 50% of the parent element (we have to remove this restriction)

Comment: It is not the issue, but the way browser renders the code. Everything works 100% perfect.

Answer (score 0):

As you already noticed, the issue is related to `left:50%` that will restrict the width of the element to `50%` of the parent element.

One *hacky* way to overcome this is to increase the width of the parent element by adding more padding since absolute element will consider the padding-box. Then you add negative margin to rectify the added padding. You should simply pay attention to overflow:

```css
.relative {
  position: relative;
  padding:0 50%;
  margin:0 -50%;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: grey;
  max-width: 800px;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}


.hide {
 overflow:hidden;
 height:500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hide">
<div class="relative">
  text
  <div class="absolute">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Enim recusandae doloribus nesciunt unde vitae quis aliquid laborum adipisci ipsa, dolorem repellendus nulla iure atque minus fuga sunt rem eaque animi.</div>
  text
  <div class="absolute" style="top:200px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you do you know how to make your solution also work when using max-with of percent? So `max-width: 100%` would make the absolute box have a maximum width of the relative box's width.

Comment: @user779159 simply remove max-width and don't set it and it will behave like that by default ;) By adding padding/margin I made the size of the element to be twice bigger and left:50% restrict the width to half the size so I multiplied by 2 and divided by 2.

Comment: @user779159 or use `max-width:50%` and it will behave as `max-width:100%`, you simply divide by two. If you P% you specifiy P/2%

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use flex-box to centrally align the elements in the `absolute` element, instead of using `left: 50%`.

```css
.relative {
  position: relative;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: grey;
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```