# Make CSS max-width larger than parent

Tags: html, css, css-position

https://jsfiddle.net/d3yns9b6/ shows how `max-width` doesn't work when I want to set it to something larger than the containing element.

Since it's absolutely positioned it should be able to extend outside the containing element. If I set an exact value using `width` it works but then both pieces of text in the example are exactly that width.

I want them both to take up **as little** width as they need, **up to a maximum** of the amount I set (**even if it exceeds** the parent container).

```css
.out {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.in {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 600px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="out">
  <div class="in">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam commodi saepe, magnam aliquid quisquam cum ex corrupti sequi aut eius harum animi vitae, exercitationem eaque tempore culpa at itaque explicabo.
  </div>
  <div class="in" style="margin-top:300px">
    Lorem
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: like this? https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/2w90urj5/9/

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith No the yellow background on the second piece of text is taking up the full width of the blue portion. It should only take as little space as it needs.

Answer (score 3):

Well, when no `width` is provided, it will fall back to `auto`, meaning it will use the width given by the parent element, regardless of absolute positioning or any `max-width`. So you need to specify *any* width, using percentage or relative units like `vh` or `vw`.

```css
.out {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.in {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500%;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.in > span {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="out">
  <div class="in">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam commodi saepe, magnam aliquid quisquam cum ex corrupti sequi aut eius harum animi vitae, exercitationem eaque tempore culpa at itaque explicabo.</span>
  </div>
  <div class="in" style="margin-top:300px">
    <span>Lorem</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The first piece of text is breaking out of the containing element as I'd like but the second piece of text is now taking up the full width, not the minimum it needs.

Comment: I can't currently think of any way to achieve that for the div directly. But if you need to preserve the background colour only behind the width of the text content, you could add an additional `<span>` around the text with `display: inline-block` and the `background-colour` applied to it instead. I updated my snippet.

Comment: @user779159 I agree with this answer. You can't do it with the given HTML structure, you're going to have to add or rearrange elements.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the width with `width` and constrain it with `max-width`.

Something like this:

```
.in {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100vw;
  max-width: 600px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: The first piece of text is breaking out of the containing element as I'd like but the second piece of text is now taking up the full width, not the minimum it needs.

Comment: The second piece of text is taking up the full width because it is the same `.in` styling class that you are using for the first piece of text.  If you want different behavior for that, you should use a different styling class for it

Answer (score 1):

This is the logical behavior of absolute element where their width obey to the *shrink-to-fit* algorithm thus they cannot exceed the available width of their containing block.

> the shrink-to-fit width is: `min(max(preferred minimum width, available width), preferred width)`. <sup>[ref](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width)</sup>

One idea is to increase the available width by increasing the padding since absolute element consider the padding-box then you can apply negative margin to compensate the padding added.

```css
.out {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  padding-right:400px; /*width + padding = 600px (equal to max-width)*/
  margin-right:-400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: blue;
  background-clip:content-box; /* We don't show the background on the padding*/
}

.in {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 600px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="out">
  <div class="in">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam commodi saepe, magnam aliquid quisquam cum ex corrupti sequi aut eius harum animi vitae, exercitationem eaque tempore culpa at itaque explicabo.
  </div>
  <div class="in" style="margin-top:300px">
    Lorem
  </div>
</div>
```

In this case the padding is not really needed since it's a block element but it can be useful when dealing with inline elements.

Example:

```css
.out {
  position: relative;
  display:inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  padding-right:400px; /*width + padding = 600px (equal to max-width)*/
  margin-right:-400px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: blue;
  background-clip:content-box; /* We don't show the background on the padding*/
}

.in {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 600px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.extra {
  display:inline-block;
  background:red;
  vertical-align:top;
  margin-top:100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="out">
  <div class="in">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laboriosam commodi saepe, magnam aliquid quisquam cum ex corrupti sequi aut eius harum animi vitae, exercitationem eaque tempore culpa at itaque explicabo.
  </div>
  <div class="in" style="margin-top:200px">
    Lorem
  </div>
</div>
<div class="extra">
  some content here 
</div>
```

Comment: I was sure I saw this before and it was with you on the a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56185720/8620333